# What are the steps to solve this problem on multi function optimization

Tags: matrix-calculus

Problem:
I have 3 rooms with limited food consumption and limited oxygen. Only a certain amount of people with certain food consumption and breathing can be allowed in a room. Room 1 has space for 100 liters of oxygen/day, and 600g of protien/day. Room 2 has space for 150 liters of oxygen/day and 700g of protien/day. Room 3 has space for 175 liters of oxygen/day and 700g of protien/day. Out of the 100 people with varying oxygen and protien consumption find the maximum amount of people for each room.

Each room has an optimization and oxygen consumption should be more important than protien consumption in the case optimizing one room over another. Another words is more valuable to save oxygen then protien.

People (A,B,C...)
R(x)o is R number oxygen optimized consumption
R(x)p is Room number protien optimized consumption

R1o = A+B+C+...<=100L
R1p = A+B+C+...<=600g
R2o = A+B+C+...<=150L
R2p = A+B+C+...<=700g
R3o = A+B+C+...<=175L
R3p = A+B+C+...<=700g

Comment: This sounds like homework, so please ass the `self-study` tag. Also it seems more like a linear programming problem rather than a statistics problem, so you might be better asking this at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EdM OP could be trying to keep Matt Damon alive on Mars...!